# Terraform template variables from other Terraform resources

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have Terraform that is using a templated bash script to set my user data section for an AWS launch configuration.

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/user-data.tpl")}"

  vars {
    file_system_id = "${aws_efs_mount_target.my_efs_alpha.dns_name}"
  }
}
```

The `file_system_id` variable then needs to be used in my template:

`sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $$$${file_system_id}:/ /mnt/efs`

Bash will interpret a single dollar sign as a bash variable. As I understand it, Terraform will interpret a double-dollar-sign as a Terraform variable. For added fun, the dollar signs in the template need to be escaped with another dollar sign -- hence the 4 dollar signs in front of `file_system_id`.

Looking at the user data in my Launch Config over in AWS Console, Terraform does not appear to be making any effort to replace my `$$$${file_system_id)` with the variable value from my template_file definition. Rather, it just shows up in the user data section as literally `$${file_system_id}`.

So, the question is, how do I get my EFS DNS name (or whatever other value I want) to replace the file_system_id variable in my template? What have I missed?

Comment: so what's wrong to use `${file_system_id}` directly in user_data.tpl?

Comment: Well, that's some humble pie for me. I figured that since it was an escape character, and since I've found cases where I need to escape the '$' with double dollar signs to get Terraform variable replacement to work, that this would be a similar case. Indeed, it looks like the single dollar sign works here. Feel free to submit your comment as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [BMW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498256/bmw) mentioned, you don't need to escape the dollar signs. `${file_system_id}` works just fine.

Terraform's variable-replacement in templates will run first so you don't need to worry about how Bash will parse it until *after* the variables are replaced.